# How to enable linting in r package in gitlab ci/cd pipeline

Tags: r, gitlab-ci, r-package

I have created CI pipeline in gitlab for r-package. I need to capture the lint output and fails the job if there is any lint error. I'm unable to read the output of lintr command.

```
image: r-base:4.1.2

stages:
  - LintR

LintR:
  stage: LintR
  script:
    - cd .. 
    - R -e "capture.output(lintr::lint_package(\"./test-r/\"), file=\"./lint_output.txt\")"
    - cd isp-r && mv ../lint_output.txt .
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./lint_output.txt
    when: always
```

How to capture the output in gitlab CI/CD

Comment: Could you include the output of the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
image: r-base:4.1.2

stages:
  - LintR

LintR:
  stage: LintR
  script:
    # redirect lintr stdout and stderr to file
    - CI="" R -e "lintr::lint_package()" &> lint_output.txt 
    # fail if file is not empty
    - [ ! -s lint_output.txt ]
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - lint_output.txt
```

Comment: Is there any exit code returned by lintR.

Comment: Yeah, this shouldn't change the exit code of lintr. If it is non-zero, the job will fail.

Comment: @user2439278, was this helpful at all?